# Prevent link event after mousdown down delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a function so that when an user clicks and holds onto a link, the link does not send the user to the appropriate link. However, the function that I used is not working. What I want is for the user to click on a link and if they hold it down for longer than one second, the link no longer works and no event is fired. After looking through it sometime, I can't find what's wrong with the code. So my question is, what did I do wrong? http://jsfiddle.net/rQP6g/2/

```
<a href="www.google.com" >link</a>

<script>
var timeoutId = 0;
    $('a').mouseup(function() {
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagation();
}, 1000);
}).bind('mouseup', function() {
clearTimeout(timeoutId);
});
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is exactly that you're trying to do.  Links are normally activated when on `click` and not just on `mousedown` so that `preventDefault` won't help. Are you trying to make it so the user has to hold down the button for a second for the link to actually work but not do anything for a shorter click. The behavior you describe is the default for me at least, I can hold the mouse button down all day and not follow a link.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. All I want is for the link to be pressed and held down, and after a second or two the link is `preventDefault`ed when I do a `mouseup`.

Comment: All of the solutions with global variables will have contention issues, each link will affect the others.

Comment: @MattWhipple Why is that a problem? You only have one mouse pointer? It seems hard to force a race condition without more than one pointer?

Comment: n/m, I was still reading the problem wrong somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work: http://jsfiddle.net/rQP6g/18/

The JS looks as follows:

```
var mousedownTime;

$('a').mousedown(function(e) {
    mousedownTime = new Date();
}).click(function(e) {
    // If the mouse has been hold down for more than 1000 milliseconds ( 1 sec. ), cancel the click
    if(Math.abs(new Date() - mousedownTime) > 1000)
        e.preventDefault();
});​
```

The basic idea is to capture the time when the mouse button is pressed down - then, when released, the click event is fired and it is computed if more than 1 sec. has elapsed since the link was pressed. If this is the case, the click event is cancelled and the link won't load :)

Comment: This wouldn't be safe from concurrency issues.

Comment: @MattWhipple Can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Every link clicked will initialize mouseDownTime.  If I click on any link thereafter it will be deactivated.  So one link will disable the whole page of links.

Comment: @MattWhipple concurrency would be a problem if somebody had 20 mouse pointers and was clicking around.. :D That can be fixed easily - simply store the `mousedownTime` as an `attribute` or `data` to the element and delete it in the click function.

Comment: @tftd - Yes, I've already commented above that I was misreading the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/rQP6g/19/ tested and working

Also your jQuery code:

```
var startingTime, timeOut = 1000;
(function($) {
    $('a').bind('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }).bind('mousedown', function(e) {
        window.startingTime = +new Date();
    }).bind('mouseup', function (e) {
        console.log('Starting time: '+ window.startingTime);
        var currentTime = +new Date();
        console.log('Current time: '+ (+new Date()));
        var difference = currentTime - window.startingTime;
        console.log (difference);
        if (difference > timeOut) {
            console.log('You are too slow, nothing happens');
        } else {
            console.log($(this).attr('href'));
            window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a reverse approach - prevent everything, then allow clicks released before a threshold:

```
// set threshold in millisecs:
var threshold = 1000;

$('a').on('click',function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    // inject current time in link element:
    $(this).attr('data-timestamp', new Date.getTime());

}, function(event){

    // check mousedown timestamp against mouseup timestamp:
    if( (new Date.getTime() - $(this).attr('data-timestamp') < threshold){

        window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');    

    }

});​​​​
```